# SPOTFIRE - Error when trying to execute a query in the information link

Tags: spotfire

When I try to write a query in the information link of Spotfire by clicking on the SQL button, I am able to execute even the complicated ones.

But when i try this very simple one, it fails

```
Select * from Table_name where Date_Value IS NOT NULL
```

Can someone please help me with a solution for this. I have tried `Date_Value = ''` but that does not give the right value. I need it by null.

```
Error message: Could not open information link.

TargetInvocationException at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework:
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. (HRESULT: 80131604)

Stack Trace:
at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.ApplicationModel.ProgressService.ExecuteWithProgressCancelable(String title, String description, ProgressOperation operation, Boolean showCancelButton)
at Spotfire.Dxp.Forms.Data.InformationDesigner.DesignerFormController.ExecuteInformationLink(CachedInformationLinkElement informationLink)


ImportException at Spotfire.Dxp.Data:
Failed to execute data source query. (HRESULT: 80131500)

Stack Trace:
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataSourceConnection.ExecuteQuery2()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataFlow.Execute()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataFlow.DataFlowConnection.ExecuteQueryCore2()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataSourceConnection.ExecuteQuery2()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Producers.SourceColumnProducer.<>c__DisplayClass15.<GetColumnsAndProperties>b__12()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.ApplicationModel.Progress.ExecuteSubtask(String title, ProgressOperation operation)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Producers.SourceColumnProducer.GetColumnsAndProperties(DataSourceConnection connection)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Persistence.DataItem.PerformUpdate(SourceColumnProducer producer, DataSourceConnection connection)
at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Persistence.DataItem.Update(SourceColumnProducer producer, DataSourceConnection connection)
at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Persistence.DataPool.<LoadData>d__2.MoveNext()
at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Producers.SourceColumnProducer.ConfigureAndLoadData()
at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.Node.ConfigureSubTree()
at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.Node.<ConfigureSubTree>b__13(Node node)
at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.Node.ConfigureSubTree()
at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.Node.<ConfigureSubTree>b__13(Node node)
at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.Node.ConfigureSubTree()
at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.Node.<ConfigureSubTree>b__13(Node node)
at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.State.NodeState.ForEachChild(IDocumentNodeChild[] children, Action`1 action)
at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.Node.ConfigureSubTree()
at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.ApplicationModel.Progress.ExecuteSubtask(String title, IndeterminateProgressFormatter progressFormatter, ProgressSpeedFormatter speedFormatter, ProgressOperation operation)
at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.DocumentNode.ConfigureAndAttachFromNew()
at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.DocumentNode.AttachSubTreeWhileExecuting(UndoableNode newOwner)
at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.DocumentNode.AttachToUndoableNode(UndoableNode newOwner)
at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.UndoableKeyedCollection`2.<>c__DisplayClass6.<Insert>b__5()
at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.Node.Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.INode.InternalTransaction(Executor executor)
at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.UndoableKeyedCollection`2.Insert(Int32 index, TNode item)
at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataTableCollection.<>c__DisplayClass20.<Add>b__1f()
at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.Node.Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.INode.InternalTransaction(Executor executor)
at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataTableCollection.Add(String dataTableName, DataSource dataSource, Boolean autoCreateFilters, Boolean includeInAxisControls)
at Spotfire.Dxp.Application.PartiallyOpenedDataSource.<LoadData>d__0.MoveNext()
at Spotfire.Dxp.Application.AnalysisApplication.<OpenPartiallyOpenedDocument>d__34.MoveNext()
at Spotfire.Dxp.Application.AnalysisApplication.<OpenDataSource>d__1b.MoveNext()
at Spotfire.Dxp.Application.AnalysisApplication.ConsumeDataLoadPromptRequests(IEnumerable`1 prompts)
at Spotfire.Dxp.Application.AnalysisApplication.Open(DataSource source, DocumentOpenSettings settings)
at Spotfire.Dxp.Forms.Data.Import.DataSourceFactoryService.OpenDataSourceWithoutPrompting(DataSource dataSource, DocumentOpenSettings documentOpenSettings, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
at Spotfire.Dxp.Forms.Data.Import.DataSourceFactoryService.OpenDataSource(InformationLinkDataSource dataSource, DocumentOpenSettings documentOpenSettings, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
at Spotfire.Dxp.Forms.Data.InformationDesigner.DesignerFormController.<>c__DisplayClass2.<ExecuteInformationLink>b__0()
at Spotfire.Dxp.Forms.Application.FormsProgressService.ProgressThread.DoOperationLoop()


InformationModelException at Spotfire.Dxp.Data:
Failed to execute query: [tibcosoftwareinc][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Incorrect syntax near ''. (HRESULT: 80131500)

Stack Trace:
at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.InformationModel.InternalInformationModelManager.DataStream.GetNextBlock()
at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.InformationModel.InternalInformationModelManager.DataStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at Spotfire.Dxp.Internal.Utilities.SeekableStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at System.IO.BinaryReader.FillBuffer(Int32 numBytes)
at System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadUInt16()
at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Formats.Sbdf.SbdfSectionHeader.ReadSectionType(BinaryReader reader, SbdfSectionTypeId expectedType)
at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Import.SbdfDataRowReader.DelayedInit()
at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Import.InformationLinkDataSourceConnection.ExecuteQueryCore2()
at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataSourceConnection.ExecuteQuery2()


InformationModelServiceException at Spotfire.Dxp.Services:
Failed to execute query: [tibcosoftwareinc][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Incorrect syntax near ''. (HRESULT: 80131509)

Stack Trace:
at Spotfire.Dxp.Services.WebServiceBase`1.InvokeService[T](ServiceMethod`1 serviceMethod, ExceptionFactoryMethod exceptionFactoryMethod)
at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.InformationModel.InternalInformationModelManager.DataStream.GetNextBlock()
```

Comment: please update your question by including the error.

Comment: Hi Niko, Since I am unable to post the full error message, please find the part where it says conversion failed  - InformationModelException at Spotfire.Dxp.Data:
Failed to get data: [tibcosoftwareinc][SQLServer JDBC Driver]Unsupported data conversion. (HRESULT: 80131500)

Comment: you should be able to include the full error inside the question. please click the "edit" link under the "spotfire" tag and update it. I have an idea of what the issue may be but I don't want to provide incorrect information.

Comment: could you also note the driver you're using to connect to the datasource? you should be able to see this in Spotfire by editing the datasource and looking in the "Type" dropdown.

Comment: In my JDBC connection to Oracle I'm able to make where statements requesting something is not null. Possible that the SQLServer JDBC driver is different but not sure.

Comment: Hi Niko,I have attached the full error message. In the Data source it is - SQL Server (Data Direct) and the connection URL is jdbc:tibcosoftwareinc:sqlserver:Server_name

Answer (score 0):

OK, it'd be more helpful if you can update the answer to the error you receive when executing `SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_value IS NULL` -- right now you are showing the error for `SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_value = ''` which I think is correct, as `''` is not a date type.

but based on your comments it looks like the error you are getting with the SQL Server (Data Direct) driver is `Unsupported data conversion.` according [some resources I found](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/827221), this is a potential bug in the JDBC driver rather than with Spotfire. you can verify if this is the case by using that driver in another application and executing the same query, or by changing the driver.

for the latter, please follow the instructions on page 29 of the [TIBCO Spotfire Server Installation and Configuration](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire_server/7.0.0/doc/pdf/TIB_sfire_server_7.0.0_installation.pdf) manual, "Install Database Drivers." as mentioned there, you'll get better performance anyway out of the vendor driver than the DD one.

if this does the trick, it would be great if you can please come back and update your original question with the error relating to the `... IS NULL` query so that anyone else running into this can more easily find the solution.

Comment: Thanks Niko for all the help. Since it was an urgent requirement, i went with creating a view and then calling the view in spotfire. I will look into your solution in more detail once I complete the critical requirement. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. One solution I didn't mention is to import the data as-is and then use Spotfire's filters to filter out "(Empty)" values.